# angular routing to component without entering full url

Tags: angular, angular-routing

When routing to a child module in my angular application, I can route to it without entering the full URL & i'm not sure why

E.G. I want to route to `admin/garage/1`, which works, but if I route to `garage/1`, it takes me to the same place (which I dont expect it to)

`localhost:4200/admin/garages/1` takes me to ViewGarageComponent, but `localhost:4200/garages/1` also takes me there, I dont expect localhost:4200/garages/1 to take me there as it is in the admin/ child routes

admin module router (i expect all these routes to be `admin/`)

```
const adminRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'admin', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: AdminComponent },
  { path: 'garages', component: GarageListComponent },
  { path: 'garage/:garageId', component: ViewGarageComponent },
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(adminRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AdminRoutingModule {}
```

admin module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AdminRoutingModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AdminComponent,
    ViewGarageComponent,
    CreateGarageComponent,
    GarageListComponent,
    HeaderComponent
  ]
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

app module router

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/sign-in', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'sign-in', component: SignInComponent },
  { path: 'register-user', component: SignUpComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'schedule', component: SyncScheduleComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'forgot-password', component: ForgotPasswordComponent },
  { path: 'verify-email-address', component: VerifyEmailComponent },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    loadChildren: () => import('./admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule), canActivate: [AdminAuthGuard]
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
```

Comment: What do you mean by " it takes me to the same place (which I dont expect it to)"

Comment: localhost:4200/admin/garages/1 takes me to ViewGarageComponent, but localhost:4200/garages/1 also takes me there, I dont expect localhost:4200/garages/1 to take me there as it is in the admin/ child route

Comment: As @AliAdravi say the garage/1 route does not exist. Use [redirect](https://angular.io/guide/router#setting-up-redirects): `{ path: '**', redirectTo: '/sign-in' }`, or [wild card](https://angular.io/guide/router#setting-up-wildcard-routes): `{ path: '**',component: PageNotFoundComponent }`

Comment: Do you have a stackblizt link for this? Looking at your routes definition, there's no way you could navigate from admin/garages to any component

Comment: @Jimmy I've created this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tsbzgt?file=src/app/admin/admin.module.ts with copied and pasted code, and it works how it is supposed to in stackblitz, but the behaviour is different in my actual code. Is there any config that could be causing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, I added `AdminModule` as an import in `AppModule` which I belive was causing it to use both routes, `admin/garage/1`, as well as `/garage/1`.

Once I removed `AdminModule` from `AppModule` the issue was resolved

Answer (score 0):

With your parent and child routes, all you have

```
admin/admin
admin/home
admin/garage
admin/garages/<1-2-3>
```

So `garage/1` route does not exist.